# Can't run any JAVA module in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After I update my Android Studio to 1.3.1 and use gradle build tool 1.3.0, I can't run any Java module in Android Studio!  At first I really was in offline mode, but when i dependent libraries , I closed it.I sync gradle after I execute `clean --refresh-dependencies`, but it doesn't work. Even I put the `lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar`in `C:\Users\.AndroidStudio1.3\system\jars\`, the problem still exists. Thank you for your help!

### LogCat

> Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'SimpleWeather'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not download lombok-ast.jar (com.android.tools.external.lombok:lombok-ast:0.2.3): No cached version available for offline mode

### build.gradle(Module:root project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.external.lombok:lombok-ast:0.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

### build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "me.rorschach.simpleweather"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java-gen']
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.0.0'
}
```

### build.gradle(Module:java module)

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao-generator:2.0.0'
}
```

Comment: make sure you are connected to internet while building your app

Comment: I'm sure that the network connection is available

Comment: try adding jar as library in your project/module

Answer (score 1):

Check your Android Studio preferences. It may be that you have checked Offline Work.

`Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Offline Work`.

Make sure that the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: At first I really was in offline mode, but when i dependent libraries , I closed it.

Comment: Did you restart Android Studio after unchecking it?